# Streaming file results on server results in char stream rather than file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering if anybody can point out why this is happening.  I have two servers, one test and one live.  I am running the same code on both.  I have a download page that when run on the test server streams a nicely formatted excel spreadsheet to the user.  When I run the same code on the live server I get, in the browser, this:

PPKÅhA·()^"?xl/workbook.xml ¢( í½`I–%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡€`$Ø@ìÁˆÍæ’ìiG#)«*ÊeVe]f@Ìí¼÷Þ{ï½÷Þ{ï½÷º;N'÷ßÿ?\fdlöÎJÚÉž!€ªÈ?~|?"_UõÛIU½Mß-Êeó¨þì£yÛ®Ý½ÛLçù"kÆÕ*_ÒwçU½ÈZú³¾¸[ŸÓüi5]/òe{wogçÓ»u^fmQ-›y±j>h·Õ¬ê<›5óLïJ£»a«ÇÌ¾Á¥Ël‘öÑë<«§óôUÞ¬Ë–°äïÎfŸ}´ûQZ?*è—W÷<˜ÜÛ{ðéƒétwïþÎG¶öñ]ƒÅÑÿPKÅhA'Q\8‘Ž[Content_Types].xml ¢( í½`I–%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡€`$Ø@ìÁˆÍæ’ìiG#)«*ÊeVe]f@Ìí¼÷Þ{ï½÷Þ{ï½÷º;N'÷ßÿ?\fdlöÎJÚÉž!€ªÈ?~|?"þÇ¿÷|ü{¼[”ée^7Eµüì£ÝñÎGi¾œV³byñÙGëö|ûà£ßãèñ›ëUÞ¤ÔtÙ|öÑ¼mWîÞm¦ó|‘5ãj•/é›óª^d-ýY_Ü]eÓ·ÙE~wogçÓ»ÓjÙæËv»ŒŽ?ÍÏ³uÙ¦§ïècé–^ÿ(=‘vèê³²Õª,¦YK_ß½\Î:lWççÅ4ŸUÓõ‚^7«:ÏfÍ<ÏÛE9æŸãEV,?aÀw£}ÖyÙ¼_§:ª1½Émšy±j6uñÓ«‹NÅdùéU~Áï|I„¯‹Yž¾ÌêöE¶ wß•w¯ªú-¢¹Ë?vÇß,,|‹ü"³:»"FhÌ/Žˆº©ã¦½.óæƒ{ëð½±ëyVç³×mÓø°-"wYºŽþPK ÂhA"X™|''_rels/.rels ¢( ï»¿PKÅhAÌñ?o¥+j>xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml ¢( í½`I–%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡€`$Ø@ìÁˆÍæ’ìiG#)«*ÊeVe]f@Ìí¼÷Þ{ï½÷Þ{ï½÷º;N'÷ßÿ?\fdlöÎJÚÉž!€ªÈ?~|?"ÿïez™×MQ-?ûhw¼óQš/§Õ¬X^|öÑº=ß>øè÷8z|UÕo›yž·)5_6êÏ>š·íêÑÝ»Ítž/²f\­ò%}w^Õ‹¬¥?ë‹»Õùy1ÍŸVÓõ"_¶w÷vv>½[çeÖRWÍ¼X5   ´ÛÀjVužÍ…E) Y±üèèñ¬ èÀ>­óóÏ>:Þ}ôÕîîÁGéÝ£ÇÜü'‹üªñ~O1–IU½Åg³Ï>Úá¶w{Ÿq÷/ët–Ÿgë²}U]};/.æ-‘é>¿3­Ê†ÿMˆ÷QºÈÞñÏ«bÖÎ?ûhïÁøþ§÷<Ü»ÿà€¾˜...

I'm wondering if this is a server settings, is the default character set overiding what I have set?  How do I amend this?

Thanks.

Comment: What headers to you get if you look at it in Fiddler or something? That looks like an Excel Spreadsheet being opened by something that doesn't know that it's an Excel Spreadsheet and is just showing it as text. (You always have an octet stream, and never a file, on the web, it's for the next step to decide what to do with it). It wants to be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for .xlsx, `application/vnd.ms-excel` for .xls

Comment: The headers were correct and yes set to application/vnd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, for the replies they are greatly appreciated.  It turns out that the problem was not having that for the file to be send and displayed correctly the buffering (Buffer = "true") had to be set in the page directive.  The headers are cleared, page created in it's entirety and then pushed to the user.  This was a .net project that pumps results from our db in .xlsx to mobile devices.  A little (or a big) pain but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Office MIME types are registered on the server that is not working

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309278(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: The MIME types were correctly set, but thanks it made me start thinking about it.